# json data appears in a single line

Tags: json

I have a badly formatted json file

`R˜{"xData":{"x":[7872,7904,...4670]}}  R˜{"xData":{"x":[7904,7904,...8000]}} ...`

That is, there is only one line, whereas each new data record should start with a new line starting from the character R. Also, the character ~ after R is unwanted. Since the file is about 1GB, it is impossible to manually insert a new line just before each R. Each x is a vector of the same number of data points, say 5000. If the total number of lines are 100000, i.e. 1e5 occurences of the character R, then how to obtain a separate output file containing only the matrix of x values in that output file? This matrix will be 5000 columns by 100000 rows.

Comment: You can try http://jsonlint.com/ to validate and format the `JSON`.

Comment: Doesn't take. File too big.